# How to associate visual studio 2012 with SQL files in Windows 8?

Tags: file-association, sql, visual-studio-2012

I'm using Windows 8 and I'm trying to make Visual Studio 2012 the default program with which to open my `.sql` files.

I have right-clicked on a `.sql` file and chosen: Open with... > Choose default program... > More options > Look for another app on this PC.  I use the form to open `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe`, but I then get the following error:

> Cannot associate file type with this program
>
> The program you have selected cannot be associated with this file type. Please choose another program.

I have associated `.sql` files with the `Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, T-SQL Editor` under Tools > Options > Text Editor > File Extension.  However, I believe this is just for syntax highlighting.

Whilst looking for a solution, I found this SO.SE question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471739/how-to-add-a-new-file-association-to-visual-studio.  However, I'm hoping for a solution that does not involve using a third-party program.

I also found this SO.SE question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996907/reassociate-files-types-for-visual-studio-2012.  However, I don't see `.sql` in the list of available file extensions.

**Is it possible to set Visual Studio 2012 as the default editor for .sql files and, if it is, how can this be achieved on Windows 8?**

Comment: Did you tried the registry trick?

Comment: @The_aLiEn What registry trick? (that's a no :))

Comment: In registry you can search for extension and change associated application to which you want. Extension associations are in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT

Answer (score 1):

You're half way of the solution.

To make VS as default editor to your SQL files.

- Right-click on any `.sql` file extension.
- Choose **Open With**.
- Now **Choose Another app**
- From the list, search for **Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector**
- Make it your Default app

if the application didn't appear in the list, You can also find it at this location

32-bit

```
%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe
```

64-bit

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe
```

Comment: aaaand warning to future readers: for many, if not most use cases, it is pointless to associate visual studio with a file type that it is not already associated with, (at least using the above mechanism,) because if you do that, and then you try and open a file of that type from within Winows Explorer, while an instance of Visual Studio is already open, then that file will ***not*** be opened in the already-running instane of Visual Studio.  Instead, a new instance of Visual Studio will be launched just for that one file.  That's pointless and retarded.

Comment: @MikeNakis if you have an opened instance of VS, you can drag and drop the file to open it in the same instance. Because opening a file will run on a new instance in any program, that's the default of the system, unless the app is programmed to open in an active instance. Like Notepad++, it checks for an active instance before opening a new instance, and open the file using that active instance.